# Maximizing the conjugate pair of complex numbers

Tags: complex-numbers

Not sure if my title makes sense given two complex variables a and b, how do I maximize a*b + b*a ? Also, |a|^2 + |b|^2 = 1 I know the answer is a=b (this comes out of a QM problem), but the solution I read assumes a and b are real "without loss of generality". Note a*b + b*a is always real. How does one solve this when we assume a and b are complex? Thanks.

Comment: Maximizing under what conditions on $a$ and $b$? If $a$ and $b$ really are given, you also know the value of $\bar a b + a \bar b$, so there is nothing to maximize. (I assume your "$*$" denotes complex conjugation.)

Comment: typo, i replaced numbers with variables.

Comment: Your edit doesn't help, since $\bar a b + a\bar b$ can be arbitrarily large. You must have some other conditions on $a$ and $b$.

Comment: The sum of their moduli equals 1. It could N, any number, no?

Comment: I edited my comment, made an error.

Comment: $a\overline{b}+\overline{a}b=(a+b)\overline{(a+b)}-1 = |a+b|^2-1\le(|a|+|b|)^2-1\le 2(|a|^2+|b|^2)-1=1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First note that
$$|a+b|^2 = (a+b)(\overline{a+b}) = |a|^2 + |b|^2 + a\bar b + \bar a b$$
Hence, since you're assuming that $|a|^2 + |b|^2 = 1$,
$$ a\bar b + \bar a b = |a+b|^2 - |a|^2 - |b|^2 = |a+b|^2 - 1 \le (|a| + |b|)^2  - 1  \le 2(|a|^2 + |b|^2) - 1 = 1$$
where the first inequality if an equality if and only if $a = \lambda b$ for some $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}_+$ and the second if and only if $|a| = |b|$. (Using the triangle inequality and the AM-GM inequality.)

Comment: There is an infinite number of solutions then yes? a = b = x + i*sqrt(1/2 - x^2) for 0<= x <= 1/2